# hiding the keyboard when I used PickerView with textField

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I want to realize one simple app, but I have some trouble. I add textField and PickerView. When I tab at textField, PickerView is appeared. But standard keyboard is appeared too (I dont want it). And when I again tab on textField, PickerView don't appear. How can I receive this problem? Thank's a lot!

This is my code:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!

    var age = ["8", "18", "28", "38", "48"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return age.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 {
        }
        return age[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 {
            self.textField1.text = self.age[row]
            self.pickerView1.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == self.textField1 {
            self.pickerView1.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: just set on property of textfield on UIPickerView didselect textfield.regisonfirstresponder()

Comment: Here is the useful library to do the same.
[IQDropDownTextField](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQDropDownTextField)

or use  self.textfiled.inputView = self.pickerView;
hope this work

Comment: in what part of my code I should add this? Can you show me this pice, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why you are not try the simple way, just add your pickerview as inputview of your textfield

```
 textField1.inputView = pickerView1
```

> This will not give you a direct way to dismiss the view since your UIPickerView has no return button, which is why I recommend to use the inputAccessoryView property to display a toolbar with a done button

```
  let myToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(320), height: CGFloat(44)))
    //should code with variables to support view resizing
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.inputAccessoryViewDidFinish))
    //using default text field delegate method here, here you could call
    //myTextField.resignFirstResponder to dismiss the views
    myToolbar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    lblcurrentText.inputAccessoryView = myToolbar
```

and call the function as

```
    func inputAccessoryViewDidFinish() {
    lblcurrentText.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

at the same time after selection on your pickerview hide the text field like

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == pickerView1 {
        self.textField1.text = self.age[row]
        self.inputAccessoryViewDidFinish()
    }
}
```

**Tutorial**

for example you can get the step by step tutorial in [here](https://blog.apoorvmote.com/uipickerview-as-inputview-to-uitextfield-in-swift/)

Comment: Anbu.Karthik thanks a lot! tutorial helped me)) but now, I don't know how to hide pickerView when I ended enter data to textField.                               func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }                                                                                                      doesn't work

Comment: this is the line you can hide the picker `lblcurrentText.resignFirstResponder()`